# How to test a power bi report?

Tags: testing, automation, powerbi, etl

Is there any other way I can test a power bi report or any etl things ?

I am a QA who does automation and quality testing for applications and bi reports. So i mostly use sql queries or sometimes python that almost match the dax to test the power bi reports. I am looking for some good resources to learn from too

Comment: I'm a report developer and can share only with my experience. When I create a measure I use desktop version with different visulas and column rows combinations. If I get correct values in all tests then the measure is fine for me ). Then, I check boomarks, all slicers, filters and its synhronization and "what if" cases. Then, I check UX/UI and test it with somebody. Regarding methology I didn't meet it yet. Not sure that it was usefull for you, but if you find some usefull resourse, please add it to an answer body.